# Brightness Icon

Tags: unity, laptop, icons, indicator, brightness

Before Icon Brightness was appearing Hotkey (FN+Arrow Right) Whenever i wanted to change my brightness the icon appears on right side of Ubuntu.

But then it suddenly stopped working, it was changing the Icon to lower brightness or upper, without brightness effects to screen.

After i changed:

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

Line changed:

From

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

To

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Now problem was resolved whenever i hit hokey brightness was changing, but without brightness indicator Icon??

How can i bring back brightness indicator whenever i change brightness it indicates "Line of Brightness" it is.??

My Laptop: Acer Aspire E1 570G
Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks for HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing the below line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

Comment: Now Brightness, not even changing...

Comment: No Brightness Icon and brightness no longer changing.

Comment: OK I have added the line still no icon :(

Answer (score 0):

You should update your kernel.. I have an Acer ultrabook and every distribution based on Ubuntu 14.10 and other  previous versions fails to work properly with Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and graphics. 
On the other hand, since the update to 15.04, the new available kernel is 3.19..... This one includes all the hotkeys of the new laptops, and works perfectly with all of the hardware.

You shouldn't really update kernel unless something is really wrong. Sadly this is the case... Follow this page to update your kernel:

http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/linux-kernel-3-19-3-released-install-update-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-other-debian-based-distros

After the update, reboot and it should be just fine!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

use the following resources if you don't have them:

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/indicator-brightness/ppa/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/indicator-brightness/ppa/ubuntu trusty main`

Try the following and see if problem solved:

`sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness`

Comment: Unable to locate Package. This package doesn't exist.